# Enumerate installed Packages in Windows 8+ with Delphi 10

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, windows-runtime

Delphi 10 comes with Windows RT headers translated to Pascal. Based on [this C++ code](https://ivanbrug.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/old-fashion-approach-to-win8-modern-apis/) i am trying to enumerate all installed Metro applications in Windows 8+. The only problem is, that i don't know how to get iterator correctly, from `IIterable_1__IPackage`. `FindPackages` method of `Deployment_IPackageManager` is called correctly, and i can confirm it by scanning memory process (before and after method call). Process memory contains strings like Microsoft.SkypeApp etc. so packages are ready to be iterated. Once i set `IIterator_1__IPackage` to first package, it becomes invalid pointer value (on my PC that is $3). I wonder now, if it has something to do with incorrect RT headers in Delphi or me approaching iteration process wrong way (most likely). Current code:

```
program PackagesManager;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  WinAPi.Management,
  WinApi.ApplicationModel,
  WinApi.WinRT,
  System.Win.ComObj;

var
  LClassId: HString;
  pInspectable: IInspectable;
  pAct: IActivationFactory;
  packageManager: Deployment_IPackageManager;
  pkgs: IIterable_1__IPackage;
  pIter: IIterator_1__IPackage;
  hasCurrent: Boolean;
  packageId: IPackageId;
  package: IPackage;
begin
  // COM/Runtime Object Initialization
  OleCheck(RoInitialize(RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED));

  try
    if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(SDeployment_PackageManager),
      Length(SDeployment_PackageManager), LClassId)) then
    begin
      // Get the activation factory
      OleCheck(RoGetActivationFactory(LClassId, IActivationFactory,
        pInspectable));

      // Activate or create an instance from the Activation Factory
      pAct := pInspectable as IActivationFactory;
      pAct.ActivateInstance(pInspectable);

      // Extract the PackageManager via QueryInterface
      OleCheck(pInspectable.QueryInterface(Deployment_IPackageManager,
        packageManager));

      // Get the `IIterable` Collection of all packages
      //
      // after below call, process memory contains strings with package names
      // i.e. Microsoft.SkypeApp, it means FindPackages was called properly
      // confirmed this by scanning process memory for known strings,
      // before and after FindPackages call
      pkgs := packageManager.FindPackages;

      // Get the Iterator from the IIterable
      pIter := pkgs.First; // pIter is now $00000003...

      hasCurrent := pIter.HasCurrent; // obviously Access Violation
      while hasCurrent do
      begin
        package := pIter.Current;
        packageId := package.Id;
        hasCurrent := pIter.MoveNext;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    RoUninitialize;
  end;
end.
```

I'm not looking for read registry or set NTFS access in `%programfiles\WindowsApps` solution, because this is just a base for project that functionality will be expanded. Being able to list all packages in elegant & Microsoft designed way would be a great start.

Comment: [Working examples from MS (C++, C#)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Package-Manager-Inventory-ee821079).

Comment: Enumerating packages requires admin privileges. Are you running your app as admin when it fails?